# Vaadin CKEditor component not showing asterix when setRequired is TRUE

Tags: ckeditor, vaadin

I am using CKEditor in my vaadin application. I am having issues where the CKEditor is not showing asterix symbol for mandatory fields even if required field is set to TRUE.

Comment: most likely there is a value there like `<div></div>`

Comment: What's the parent of the CKEditor instance? Some component containers doesn't render required indicator..